# TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'address', 'postCode', 'email', 'phone', 'dob'];
    for (var i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
            if (!$('#'+fields[i]).val()) {
                alert('The ' + getFieldTitle(fields[i]) + ' field is required.');


                return false;
            }
            values.fields[i] = $('#'+fields[i]).val();
            console.log($('#'+fields[i]).val() , values , fields[i]);
        }
```

Values is defined as a global variable at the beginning of the script. It seems that on the first iteration of assigning the proper name to the array position I get a failure. What i log the field names they appear to show up correctly but they don't get assigned to the array values properly?

EDIT: Left out the fields initialization at first, sorry about that

Comment: How you initial `fields` array ?

Comment: Is `values` initialized with a "fields" property?  If not, then that's your problem.

Comment: The idea was to have values.firstName ect....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an object containing the id and value:

```
// set values equal to an empty object
var values={};
var fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'address', 'postCode', 'email', 'phone', 'dob'];
for (var i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
        if (!$('#'+fields[i]).val()) {
            alert('The ' + getFieldTitle(fields[i]) + ' field is required.');
            return false;
        }
// Here's the only line you need to change
        values[fields[i]] = $('#'+fields[i]).val();
        console.log($('#'+fields[i]).val() , values , fields[i]);
    }
```

Comment: this is solution that i wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
(values.fields || (values.fields = []))[i] = $('#'+fields[i]).val();
```

Comment: I don't want values. fields however. I want the end result to be something along the lines of values.firstName, values.lastName, ect....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var values = {},
    i = 0,
    l = fields.length;
for (i; i < l; i++) {
    var itemId = fields[i],
        item = document.getElementById(itemId),
        itemValue = item.value;    
    if (!itemValue) {
        alert('The ' + getFieldTitle(item) + ' field is required.');
        return false;
    }
    values[itemId] = itemValue;
}
```

There is no need to use jQuery here. Your solution will be faster with just JavaScript

Comment: I don't want values. fields however. I want the end result to be something along the lines of values.firstName, values.lastName, ect....